# Segmentation fault (core dumped) issue c++: dynamic memory

Tags: c++

```
 template<class T>
   void SimpleList<T>::in_node_l(void){
       Node* fin;
       fin=new Node;
       (*last).next=fin;
       last=fin;        
       size++;
}
```

I get Segmentation fault(core dumped) error when in_node_l member function is called by the function push

```
 template<class T>
   void stack<T>::push(T var){
       SimpleList<T>::in_node_l();
       (*(this->last)).data=var;
       position++;
       return;
  }
```

stack is a derived class :

```
    class stack : public SimpleList<T>
```

Node is declared as

```
template<class T>
struct SimpleList<T>::Node{
  T data;
  Node* next;
 };
```

if I call in_node_l in main however I do not get any errors.

the constructor for class stack is:

```
template<class T>

stack<T>::stack(int s,string n)
:SimpleList<T>(s,n)
{
  position=1;
}
```

constructor for SimpleList is given by

```
template<class T>
SimpleList<T>::SimpleList(int s,string n){
int i;
//name= input name
Node *prev,*current;
size=s;
name=n;
if(s==1){
    current=new Node;
    first=current;
    last=current;
    cout<<"SIMPLELIST CONSTRUCTUR"<<endl;
}
else{
    for (i=1;i<s;i++){
        current=new Node;
        if(i==1){
            first=current;
        }
        else{
            (*prev).next=current;
            if(i==s-1){
                last=current;
                if(last=(*prev).next){
                    cout<<"SIMPLELIST CONSTRUCTUR2"<<endl;
                }       
            }
        }
        prev=current;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `(*last).next=fin` -- You could have simply written this as `last->next = fin;`

Comment: Did you write a non-templated version of this class before you attempted the templated one?

Comment: I am going to guess that `last` is not initialized properly. It's hard telling what could be wrong without a [mcve].

Comment: Where is your `last` defined?

Comment: `SimpleList<T>::in_node_l();` assigns to the global variable `last`. This has nothing to do with `this->last`.

Comment: `fin` is assigned twice, and `last->next` is lost...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).